# floating DIV doesn't get wrapped by paragraph, possibly because of defined width of paragraph?

Tags: html, css

Within a DIV, I'm trying to float an image to the right, and have a paragraph wrap around it.  That's it.  However, because the paragraph has a width of 94% (I've got padding), it's causing a pushdown effect, preventing the div to be wrapped by it.  It's really dumb, and everything I found online is just stating something I already know (Float the image, etc... )

EDIT: ... Didn't think I'd get this much negative backlash, I'm new here.. Anyways, just got done working out, so here's the jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kMGQC/25/

```
<div id="red">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</p>
<div id="blue">

</div>
</div>



#red {
background-color: red;
position: relative; 
overflow: auto;
}

#red p {
float: left;
width: 95%;
display: block;
}

#blue {
background-color: blue;
float: right; 
width: 200px; 
height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Add [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Use align=left for inline.

Comment: You should feel even more dumb for posting that as the title. I don't understand people who like to share their stupidity with the world. How about a meaningful title with a non-sloppy, but still successful body? With relevant code and a fiddle?

Comment: I've added a jsFiddle, please take another look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have a Fiddle, I can stop randomly guessing!

Floated elements should be placed *before* the content that you want to have flow around it.

Move the `<div id="blue">` to be before the `<p>`

Comment: Tried it on the parent div and the child div just in case even though that makes no sense. It didn't really help. the overflow is currently set to auto.

Comment: I added a jsFiddle, if you can take a look at that, please do so

Comment: I just tried that as well, it still doesn't help. The blue div gets pushed above (or rather, the p get's pushed below). There is no wrapping effect.

Comment: Ah. Well in that case you'll need to remove the `width:95%` from the `p`... consider adding `margin-left` to the floated element instead.

Comment: adding a `margin-left` doesn't make any sense, if anything that would make it harder for the div within to be wrapped around.  
  
Anyways, here's the current jsFiddle  
  
http://jsfiddle.net/kMGQC/30/

Comment: really... oh wow, the other float intefered with it? thanks a lot man. I appreciate your time.